# What is the equivalent of "fractionalZoom" in OpenLayers 3.0?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

When using OpenLayers 2.13 and the http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0 WMS layer, the fractionalZoom property could be set to true for the OpenLayers.Map object.  What is the equivalent property in OpenLayers 3.0.0?

I am using the same map server source, but whenever I perform a fitExtent() on the view (using the extent of a Vector layer), the zoom is always an integer (which can result in lots of white space surrounding the view).

EDIT - Example code

Here's a simple map example using OpenLayers 2.13

```
Application.TerminalPointingMap = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "lqstsTerminalPointingMap",
    renderers: ["Canvas"],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Base Layer", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {
          layers: "basic"
        }, {
          useCanvas: OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.ONECANVASPERLAYER
        }
    ]
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    controls: [
      new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(), new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
        zoomWorldIcon: true
      }), new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
    ],
    numZoomLevels: 12,
    fractionalZoom: true
  });
```

Note the fractionalZoom property.  So my question amounts to: what is the OL3 version of this code snippet.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting Andread Hocevar](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/4045):

> OpenLayers 3 supports fractional zoom levels out of the box. All you have to do is use the view's [`setZoom`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#setZoom) method with a fractional value.

Comment: This does seem to be the case for setZoom.  However, when using fitExtent it only seems to apply integer zoom. Same with zooming with mouse wheel.

Comment: @ProfNimrod do you find out how to apply fractional zoom for FitExtent?

Comment: For touch devices (mobile phones) this does not work.  It always jumps to the nearest whole zoom level, even if you pinch-zoom only a small amount.

Comment: This has been now been fixed for touch devices using pinch-zoom.